How do I test ngOnInit in Angular?
I'm using Angular and Jasmine. I've coded an edit form for an entity called a trainer. My ngOnInit function grabs the trainer id from the url and then makes a service call to grab the trainer from the database. I'm trying to check in my test that the form data has been prepopulated by checking one field (firstName), but I keep getting the error: Expected null to be 'Devin'.
When I console.log trainerForm.value, it's null: LOG: Object{firstName: null, lastName: null, email: '', officeLocation: '', pathwaysControl: [], courses: [], skills: null}
Here's my TS file:
export class EditTrainerComponent implements OnInit {
  userId: number | undefined;

  currentPage: string = '';
  targetElementWidth: number = 0;

  offices: OfficeLocation[] = [];
  allCourses: Course[] = [];
  courses: Course[] = [];
  pathways: Pathway[] = [];
  prevPathways: string[] = []; // remove me?
  skills: Skill[] = [];

  trainerForm!: FormGroup;
  trainer: Trainer = emptyTrainer();

  experienceExpand: string = 'out';
  showModal: boolean = false;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private trainerService: TrainerService,
    private officeLocationService: OfficeLocationService,
    private courseService: CourseService,
    private pathwayService: PathwayService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private dialog: MatDialog,
    private location: Location
  ) {
    this.trainerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      firstName: [
        null,
        [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.minLength(2),
          Validators.maxLength(12),
          this.noBlankSpacesValidator,
        ],
      ],
      lastName: [
        null,
        [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.minLength(2),
          Validators.maxLength(12),
          this.noBlankSpacesValidator,
        ],
      ],
      email: [
        '',
        [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.pattern(
            '^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.)?fdmgroup.com$'
          ),
        ],
        [this.emailExistsValidator()],
      ],
      officeLocation: ['', Validators.required],
      pathwaysControl: [[]],
      courses: [[]],
      skills: [null, Validators.required],
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.trainerService.getAllSkills().subscribe((skills) => {
      this.skills = skills;
    });

    this.officeLocationService.getAllOfficeLocations().subscribe((offices) => {
      this.offices = offices;
    });

    this.courseService.getAllCourses().subscribe((courses) => {
      this.courses = courses;
      this.allCourses = courses;
    });

    this.pathwayService.getAllPathways().subscribe((pathways) => {
      this.pathways = pathways;

      // Fetch the trainer that is being edited and populate fields
      // This is inside getAllPathways because the ability to load pathways requires   
      // this.pathways to be loaded first
      const trainerId = this.getTrainerId();
      this.trainerService.getTrainerById(trainerId).subscribe((trainer) => {
        this.trainer = trainer;

        this.trainerForm.patchValue({
          firstName: this.trainer.firstName,
          lastName: this.trainer.lastName,
          email: this.trainer.email,
          officeLocation: this.trainer.officeLocation?.city,
          pathwaysControl: this.getPathwaysByCourses(
            this.trainer.coursesEligibleToTeach
          ),
          courses: this.getCourseNames(this.trainer.coursesEligibleToTeach),
          skills: this.getSkillNames(this.trainer.skills),
        });
      });
    });
  }

And here's my test file:
  describe('EditTrainerComponent', () => {
  let component: EditTrainerComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<EditTrainerComponent>;
  let mockTrainerService: jasmine.SpyObj<TrainerService>;
  let mockCourseService: jasmine.SpyObj<CourseService>;
  let mockPathwayService: jasmine.SpyObj<PathwayService>;
  let locationSpy: SpyLocation;
  let mockTrainer: Trainer;
  let mockSkills: Skill[] = [];
  let mockPathways: Pathway[] = [];
  let mockCourses: Course[] = [];

  beforeEach(async () => {
    mockTrainer = {
      userId: 14,
      firstName: "Devin",
      lastName: "Troy",
      email: "devin.troy@fdmgroup.com",
      username: "devin.troy",
      userType: {
          userTypeId: 2,
          name: "Trainer"
      },
      officeLocation: {
          id: 5,
          city: "Charlotte",
          stateOrProvince: "NC",
          country: {
              countryId: 2,
              countryName: "United States",
              region: {
                  id: 1,
                  regionName: "North America",
                  regionCode: "NA"
              },
              countryCode: "USA"
          }
      },
      dateJoined: new Date("2020-08-12T00:22:10.000+00:00"),
      bio: "",
      trainerStatus: "active",
      trainerRoles: [],
      coursesEligibleToTeach: [],
      skills: [
          {
              id: 22,
              name: "Excel"
          },
          {
              id: 5,
              name: "APM"
          }
      ],
      dateModified: new Date("2026-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00")
  };

  mockSkills = [...]
  mockPathways = [...]
  mockCourses = [...]


  mockTrainerService = jasmine.createSpyObj('TrainerService', [
      'checkIfEmailExists',
      'getAllSkills',
      'getTrainerById'
    ]);

    mockCourseService = jasmine.createSpyObj('CourseService', [
      'getCoursesByPathwayId',
    ]);

    mockPathwayService = jasmine.createSpyObj('PathwayService', [
      'getAllPathways',
    ]);

    mockCourseService.getCoursesByPathwayId.and.returnValue(of(mockCourses));
    mockTrainerService.getAllSkills.and.returnValue(of(mockSkills));
    mockTrainerService.checkIfEmailExists.and.returnValue(of(false));
    mockPathwayService.getAllPathways.and.returnValue(of(mockPathways))
    mockTrainerService.getTrainerById.and.returnValue(of(mockTrainer));

    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [EditTrainerComponent],
      imports: [
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([]),
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatSelectModule,
        NoopAnimationsModule,
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: TrainerService, useValue: mockTrainerService },
        { provide: Location, useClass: SpyLocation },
      ],
    }).compileComponents();

    locationSpy = TestBed.inject(Location) as SpyLocation;

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EditTrainerComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    component.trainer = mockTrainer;
    component.pathways = mockPathways;
    component.courses = mockPathways[0].courses;

    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  // HERE IS MY TEST THAT IS FAILING:
  fit('should show values for existing trainer', async() => {
    mockTrainerService.getTrainerById.and.returnValue(of(mockTrainer));
    
    fixture.detectChanges();
    await fixture.whenStable();

    expect(component.trainerForm).toBeDefined(); // passes
    expect(component.trainerForm.controls['firstName']).toBeTruthy(); // passes

    expect(component.pathways).toEqual(mockPathways); // passes

    console.log(component.trainerForm.value) // logs obj with null values

    expect(component.trainerForm.get('firstName')?.value).toBe(mockTrainer.firstName); // FAILS
  });


If your ngOnInit is too long, it is better to split it into small chunks of function and test separately each function. You don't need to setup fakeAsync if it is not necessary

You can use fakeAsync and flush from angular testing, to wait for asynchronous actions to complete.
You have to call the ngOnInit inside the test case for the values to be set.
You can remove the fixture.detectChanges() and just trigger the ngOnInit method manually.
it('should show values for existing trainer', fakeAsync(() => {
  mockPathwayService.getAllPathways.and.returnValue(of(mockPathways));
  mockTrainerService.getTrainerById.and.returnValue(of(mockTrainer));
  component.ngOnInit();
  flush();
  expect(component.trainerForm).toBeDefined(); // passes
  expect(component.trainerForm.controls['firstName']).toBeTruthy(); // passes

  expect(component.pathways).toEqual(mockPathways); // passes

  console.log(component.trainerForm.value); // logs obj with null values

  expect(component.trainerForm.get('firstName')?.value).toBe(
    mockTrainer.firstName
  ); // FAILS
}));

Full Code:
import {
  TestBed,
  ComponentFixture,
  waitForAsync,
  fakeAsync,
  flush,
} from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent, PathwayService, TrainerService } from './app.component';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { SpyLocation } from '@angular/common/testing';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

describe('EditTrainerComponent', () => {
  let component: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  let mockPathwayService: jasmine.SpyObj<PathwayService> = jasmine.createSpyObj(
    'PathwayService',
    ['getAllPathways']
  );
  let mockTrainerService: jasmine.SpyObj<TrainerService> = jasmine.createSpyObj(
    'TrainerService',
    ['getTrainerById']
  );
  let locationSpy: SpyLocation;
  let mockTrainer: any = {
    userId: 14,
    firstName: 'Devin',
    lastName: 'Troy',
    email: 'devin.troy@fdmgroup.com',
    username: 'devin.troy',
    userType: {
      userTypeId: 2,
      name: 'Trainer',
    },
    officeLocation: {
      id: 5,
      city: 'Charlotte',
      stateOrProvince: 'NC',
      country: {
        countryId: 2,
        countryName: 'United States',
        region: {
          id: 1,
          regionName: 'North America',
          regionCode: 'NA',
        },
        countryCode: 'USA',
      },
    },
    dateJoined: new Date('2020-08-12T00:22:10.000+00:00'),
    bio: '',
    trainerStatus: 'active',
    trainerRoles: [],
    coursesEligibleToTeach: [],
    skills: [
      {
        id: 22,
        name: 'Excel',
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        name: 'APM',
      },
    ],
    dateModified: new Date('2026-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00'),
  };
  let mockSkills: any[] = [];
  let mockPathways: any[] = [];
  let mockCourses: any[] = [];

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent],
      imports: [],
      providers: [
        { provide: TrainerService, useValue: mockTrainerService },
        { provide: PathwayService, useValue: mockPathwayService },
        { provide: Location, useClass: SpyLocation },
      ],
    }).compileComponents();

    // locationSpy = TestBed.inject(Location) as SpyLocation;

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  // HERE IS MY TEST THAT IS FAILING:
    it('should show values for existing trainer', fakeAsync(() => {
      mockPathwayService.getAllPathways.and.returnValue(of(mockPathways));
      mockTrainerService.getTrainerById.and.returnValue(of(mockTrainer));
      component.ngOnInit();
      flush();
      expect(component.trainerForm).toBeDefined(); // passes
      expect(component.trainerForm.controls['firstName']).toBeTruthy(); // passes

      expect(component.pathways).toEqual(mockPathways); // passes

      console.log(component.trainerForm.value); // logs obj with null values

      expect(component.trainerForm.get('firstName')?.value).toBe(
        mockTrainer.firstName
      ); // FAILS
    }));
});

